# PreparedStatement parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting a parameter index out of range error when executing a prepared statement. I have several other statements working correctly. The only difference with this query is it's the only UPDATE. The rest are all INSERT, ADD, DELETE etc. Any guidance on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
sqlStatement = "UPDATE customer SET customerName = ?, addressId = ? WHERE customerId = ?;";

StatementHandler.setPreparedStatement(ConnectionHandler.connection, sqlStatement);

StatementHandler.getPreparedStatement().setString(1, name);
StatementHandler.getPreparedStatement().setInt(2, AddressDAO.getAddressId(address));
StatementHandler.getPreparedStatement().setInt(3, customerId);
StatementHandler.getPreparedStatement().executeUpdate();
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

I have put a couple print statement sin the middle of the code block and it seems to fail on the 3rd parameter. All values coming in are valid and match the types being assigned. MySQL is being used and the statement works fine if executed in the console.

Thank you for reading and any help you can provide.

Edit: Here is the statement handler method I am using as well. I am combing through to see what else I should add to help get this thing figured out. Thank you for the comments!

```
public class StatementHandler {

    /**
     * create statement reference
     */
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    /**
     * method to create statement object
     */
    public static void setPreparedStatement(Connection connection, String sqlStatement) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
    }

    /**
     * getter to return statement object
     */
    public static PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(){
        return preparedStatement;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `StatementHandler.getPreparedStatement()` isn't returning the same instance each time, could you add the code of this method ? Also bear in mind that if `StatementHandler` is called by different threads, the prepared statement object may well be replaced between two `getPreparedStatement()` calls .

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet doesn't make it clear, but I can guess. I'll list a series of conclusions I'm drawing; you'd have to doublecheck these:

1. StatementHandler is a class (not a variable). (reason: You've capitalized it).
2. setPreparedStatement and getPreparedStatement are static methods in the StatementHandler class. (follows naturally).
3. You are using multiple threads (reason: That would be sufficient to explain this problem).
4. You aren't synchronizing (reason: Same as #3).

Then this result is obvious: You can't do that. Your entire VM has one global 'prepared statement' with multiple threads calling setPreparedStatement and getPreparedStatement in more or less arbitrary orders. One thread calls setPreparedStatement, then another thread does, then the first tries to get the prepared statement the other one set, and it all goes to hades in a handbasket.

You can't do it this way. Heck, you can't even share a connection between two threads (as they'd be getting in each other's way and messing up your transactions).

If you don't quite get what static does (And it is, admittedly, a bit of an advanced topic), don't ever use it. You can pretty much write all the java you'd ever want without using static methods. The one exception is `public static void main` which must be static, but just make that the one-liner: `new MyClass().go();`, with go() being a non-static method, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to go one step further than rzwitserloot and presume that your `AddressDAO` uses StatementHandler, too.

The query for `AddressDAO.getAddressId(address)` has probably one parameter, which matches the 1 from the Exception, and replaces the prepredStatemt before setting the third parameter.

As proof it would be suffient assigning `AddressDAO.getAddressId(address)` to a variable(and use it afterwards) before setting the prepared statement.

Alternativly you can get once the prepared statement in a variable and use this variable afterwards.